# Função com número variado de parâmetros via template

Tags: c++, funções, parâmetros, template

Sei que os templates em definições de funções faz, para cada configuração que ele possibilita, compilar uma função distinta.

Quero saber se é possível criar funções de número variado de parâmetros de tal maneira que compile uma função específica para aquela configuração de parâmetros.

Quer dizer, se dá para fazer algo que siga uma lógica assim, sem precisar de bibliotecas e que gere o código otimizado especialmente para aquele "n" específico.

```
template< int n >
int min( int arg[0] , int arg[1] , ... , int arg[n-1] ){
    int _min = (-1<<31)-1 , i ;
    for( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
        if( arg[i]<_min )
            _min = arg[i] ;
    return _min ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível, com *variadic template*:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> T
min_vt(T x)
{
    return x;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args> T
min_vt(T x, T y, Args... args)
{
    T z = min_vt(y, args...);
    return x < z ? x : z;
}
```

Mas existem outras maneiras de fazer algo similar ao que você quer. Veja a seguir.

Usando *variable argument lists* (`va_list`), que funciona em C puro também, mas você precisa especificar a quantidade de argumentos passados para a função:

```
template <typename T> T
min_va(int nargs, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, nargs);
    T val = va_arg(ap, T);
    for (int i = 2; i <= nargs; i++) {
        T a = va_arg(ap, T);
        if (a < val)
            val = a;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return val;
}
```

Utilizando *functor* que retorna o próprio objeto:

```
template <typename T>
class
min_functor
{
private:
    T value;
public:
    min_functor(T v)
        : value(v)
    {
    }

    min_functor &operator()(T v) {
        if (v < value)
            value = v;
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream &
    operator<<(ostream &os, min_functor<T> rhs)
    {
        os << rhs.value;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Implementando manualmente a mesma função com quantidades diferentes de argumentos recebidos:

```
template <typename T> T
min_multisig(T a0, T a1)
{
    return a0 < a1 ? a0 : a1;
}

template <typename T> T
min_multisig(T a0, T a1, T a2)
{
    return min_multisig(min_multisig(a0, a1), a2);
}

template <typename T> T
min_multisig(T a0, T a1, T a2, T a3)
{
    return min_multisig(min_multisig(min_multisig(a0, a1), a2), a3);
}
```

E o código para testar:

```
int
main()
{
    cout << min_vt(1234, 1222) << endl;
    cout << min_vt(12.34, 12.22, 13.33) << endl;

    cout << min_va<int>(2, 1234, 1222) << endl;
    cout << min_va<double>(3, 12.34, 12.22, 13.33) << endl;

    cout << min_functor<int>(1234)(1222) << endl;
    cout << min_functor<double>(12.34)(12.22)(13.33) << endl;

    cout << min_multisig<int>(1234, 1222) << endl;
    cout << min_multisig<double>(12.34, 12.22, 13.33) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```